# Spaces having a dense subset of isolated points

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Is there anything known about spaces having a dense subset consisting of isolated points?

Comment: Well, for one thing, it have to fail a lot of separation axiom, because even with $T_{1}$ it's already impossible.

Comment: I mean isolated in the whole space.

Comment: @Gina: The subspace $X = \{ 0 , \frac 11 , \frac 12 , \frac 13 , \ldots \}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has a dense subset consisting of isolated points of $X$, namely $X \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and $X$ is perfectly normal.  (Even more trivially, every discrete space is an example of such a space.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer:You are right, that was a gap in logic, forgot that special case. So now my answer might be trivial or slightly less trivial depend on what the question is asking (I interpret isolated point in this question as in isolated in the set as subspace). So now $X$ either fail $T_{1}$ or the dense subset would have to contains exactly all point that are isolated point in $X$.

Comment: @Gina: By "isolated" the OP means isolated in the entire space.  Although you are correct that if $X$ has a dense set of isolated points, then this set must be the family of _all_ isolated points. (As "$x$ isolated in $X$" means that $\{ x \}$ is open in $X$ it follows that every dense set must contain all isolated points).

Comment: @ArthurFischer:oh so the OP is asking something else. What I meant is that if the space fulfill $T_{1}$ then the opposite is also true, that is every point in the dense set must be isolated in $X$ too. I wrongly assumed that there are non-isolated point in the dense set, which was why I concluded it fails $T_{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Such spaces can be very general. For instance, take a separable space with dense subset $b_n$, and cross it with $R$.

Then for each $n$, put a point at $(b_n,1/n)$. This is a set of isolated points, and the closure of this set contains a copy of the original space.

This probably works for non-separable spaces, too, with some modifications.

So such spaces can essentially be any space (may need separability) with some isolated points thrown in.